# Can I avoid explicitly writing a constructor for each struct in a std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, aggregate-initialization

Consider this code:

```
#include <variant>

struct x {
  int y;
};

int main() {
  std::variant<x> v(std::in_place_type<x>, {3}); /*1*/
  return std::get<x>(v).y;
}
```

This does not compile and neither does when removing the `{}` from the line `/*1*/`, even though aggregate initialization

```
x a{3};
x b({3});
```

works in both "constructor-like" forms. Can I somehow make the `std::variant` initializer aware of the possibility of constructing structs using aggregate initialization without having to write boring boilerplate constructors for each struct that may be used in my real-world case?

I would expect this to work, somehow, as per [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) the two overloads (5) and (6) in question both say

> Constructs a variant with the specified alternative T and ***initializes*** the contained value with the arguments *[...]*

I'm using GCC 7 if that matters.

Comment: If it consoles you, `std::make_unique` and family have the same limitation :(

Comment: aggregate initialization has always been a thorn in the C++ initialization system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround for this, apart from adding a constructor. The standard mandates this for both overloads you mention, [[variant.ctor]19](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#19) and [[variant.ctor]23](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#23) respectively:

> *Effects*: Initializes the contained value as if direct-non-list-initializing an object of type `T` with the arguments `std​::​forward<Args>(args)...`.
>
> *Effects*: Initializes the contained value as if direct-non-list-initializing an object of type `T` with the arguments `il, std​::​forward<Args>(args)...`.

You can always copy or move the object using:

```
std::variant<x> v(std::in_place_type<x>, x{3});
// or more clear and does the same thing
std::variant<x> v(x{3});
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is not exactly what you are asking, but what about explicitly constructing the object instead of relying on type inference?

```
#include <variant>

struct x {
  int y;
};

int main() {
  std::variant<x> v(std::in_place_type<x>, x{3});
  return std::get<x>(v).y;
}
```

Comment: Actually I'd be happy with this! My question, per title, is about avoiding the constructor, which this achieves. It will technically involve some moving around but in simple cases the optimizer will take care of that with no overhead.

Comment: Indeed it would be straightforward if your class provides a moving constructor. As you don't want any explicitly defined constructor you should guarantee the implicit moving constructor (or defaulting one at least).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go overkill, we can create a factory type that has a conversion operator:

```
template <class... Args>
struct list_init_from {
    std::tuple<Args...> args;

    template <class T>
    operator T() {
        return std::apply([](auto... args){
            return T{args...};
        }, args);
    }   
};

template <class... Args>
list_init_from(Args... ) -> list_init_from<Args...>;
```

Which you can use:

```
std::variant<x> v(std::in_place_type<x>, list_init_from{3});
```

This works, but leaves much to be desired: perfect forwarding, SFINAE on the conversion operator, and explicitly specifying which types to allow conversions to are exercises left to the reader.